# Listing nfs shares exported on windows

Tags: windows, nfs

I want to view the nfs shares that are exported on a windows server from a linux client. I know how to view the cifs shares(by using samba's "net rpc share .." command). How do I view the nfs shares?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nfs shares are displayed using `showmount -e` command